# C++ Undefined reference to vtable in case of multi-level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(int x, int y, int width, int height):
        m_X(x),
        m_Y(y),
        m_width(width),
        m_height(height)
    {
    }
    virtual ~ Widget()
    {
        m_widgetList.clear();
    };
    virtual void AddWidget(Widget * wget)
    {
        m_widgetList.push_back(wget);
    }
    virtual void RemoveWidget(Widget * wget)
    {
        m_widgetList.remove(wget);
    }
    virtual void DebugInfo() { };
private:

    int m_X;
    int m_Y;
    int m_width;
    int m_height;

private:
    std::list<Widget*> m_widgetList;

};

class PanelWidget: public Widget
{
public:
    PanelWidget(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        : Widget(x, y, width, height)
    {

    }
    virtual ~PanelWidget()
    {

    }

    virtual void DebugInfo() { };
};

class PictureWidget: public PanelWidget
{
public:
    PictureWidget(std::string imageFileName, int x, int y, int width, int height)
        : PanelWidget(x, y, width, height),
          m_imageFileName(imageFileName)
    {

    }
    virtual ~PictureWidget();

    virtual void DebugInfo() { };

private:
    std::string m_imageFileName;

};


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Widget* mainScreen = new PanelWidget(0, 0, 800, 600);

    mainScreen->AddWidget( new PictureWidget("background.jpg", 0, 0, 800, 600));

    mainScreen->AddWidget( new PictureWidget("icon.jpg", 10, 10, 50, 50) );


    delete mainScreen;
}
```

Getting undefined reference error:

```
In function `main':
undefined reference to `vtable for PictureWidget'
undefined reference to `vtable for PictureWidget'
```

Any ideas/suggestions? Seems like I need to overload/override the Add & Remove functions in the base class correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the PictureWidget's destructor but haven't provided an implementation.

Perhaps that's preventing the compiler from generating its vtable properly or something like that leading to the error message. I don't really know offhand.

But it's a problem regardless.

Comment: By the way, Clang gives this helpful note: `a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.` It is definitely referring to the destructor.